# ¿Cómo hacer que no se repitan los mismos números?

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo hacer que al momento que yo ingrese los números no se repitan?

Mi programa tratará sobre cuáles son pares y cuáles no. Cuántos y cuáles se repiten. Estoy usando arreglos, pero se supone que debería hacer que no se repitan. No sé que más le falta o qué estoy colocando mal.

Este es mi código:

```
int valor;
String valorp = "";
String valori = "";
string valorr = "";

valor = Convert.ToInt32 (Interaction.InputBox ("¿Cuantos numeros vas a ingresar?", "", null));
int[] a = new int[valor];
textBox1.Text += ("Los numeros que ingresastes son:");

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
  a[i] = Convert.ToInt32 (Interaction.InputBox ("Ingresa el numero:", "", null));

  textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString (a[i] + ",");
}

int[] iguales = new int[a.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
  int cont = 0;

  for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++) {
    if (a[i] == a[j]) {
      cont++;
    }
  }

  if (iguales[i] != 0) {
    valorr += iguales[i] + " Se repite: " + cont + " veces " + Environment.NewLine;
  }

  if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
    valorp += a[i] + " , ";
  } else {
    valori += a[i] + " , ";
  }
}

textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString (" ") + Environment.NewLine;
textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString (" Los numeros pares son: ");
textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString (valorp) + Environment.NewLine;
textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString (" ") + Environment.NewLine;
textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString (" Los numeros imapres son: ");
textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString (valori) + Environment.NewLine;
textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString (" ") + Environment.NewLine;
textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString (" El numero: ");
textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString (valorr) + Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olvida las formaciones de datos, en su lugar usa contenedores: deja de usar `int[]` y pasa a usar `List<int>` (de [`System.Collections.Generic`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=netframework-4.8)).

Añade números a tu lista con `Add` y elimina las repeticiones con `Distinct`:

```
var numeros = new List<int>();

Console.WriteLine("Cuantos numeros?");
int valor = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine($"Se ingresaran {valor} numeros");
for (var i = 0; i != valor; ++i)
{
    int numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    numeros.Add(numero);
}

Console.WriteLine("Los numeros sin repeticiones son");
    foreach (var v in numeros.Distinct())
        Console.WriteLine($"Numero {v}");
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVFLSwMxED4nv2IsHrYUlz68rVWkgghVxAoexEPIjmtgN9FJuiJlf/s63XRVxIKHkGSY7zHfaH@kHWHbrr2xBaw@fMAqkz9/6dLYt1@lhStL1ME469NLtEhGZ1LqUnkPt@QKUpXcSOGDCkZD7UwO18rYxAdilscnUFT4oRTcI2pFYNcVkvMwB4vvsDQ@nBgbTpMhswqxYBlXYvpAJiC7wWSwWCsbGLADng24UwjGQK1KR0zEoBoppPfuyobZNOlJ7lDlHcdwH/nhYIXANgm9ImVh01E2vVaUemaRZGvdsNY44@tgHrUzGI0Mz9YN11mKwP96YtBOKT3P8yS@u3qzJ4zldxDAWwLCV@TceTvIBWej461lVPol2q55wh6UXnDgxurA@tvGPzO5iUNs6qaja2TTtpOxnMjp15nJYz4T@Qk)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias validarlo usando algo como esto

```
int i = 0;
while (i < a.Length)
{
    int nro = Convert.ToInt32(Interaction.InputBox("Ingresa el numero:", "", null));

    if(Existe(nro, a)){
        Messagebox.Show("El valor ya fue ingresado");
        continue;
    }

    a[i] = nro; 
    textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(a[i] + ",");

    i++;
}
```

la idea es controlar el `loop` usando un `while` asi puede definir cuando pasar el siguiente item, o no hacerlo si el valor ya existe

Despues lo validas usando algo como esto

```
private bool Existe(int nro, int[] lista)
{
    bool existe = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < lista.Length; i++)
    {
        if(lista[i] == nro){
            existe = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return existe;
}
```

En el ejemplo puse en MessageBox para informar que existe pero eso puede cambiarlo